# convert void* stored in std::vector to function arguments using variadic templates

Tags: templates, c++11, variadic-templates, void-pointers

I created a MemberFunctionWrapper template class that stores a function and its parameter types. It has a call method which takes a vector of void* and converts them into the parameter types needed for the function call before calling the function.

My problem is that the wrapper can only take a fixed amount of function arguments
( _arg0, _arg1 ).
I want the class to take any number of function arguments( arg0, arg1, arg2 ... argX ) How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void foo( int a, const string& b );
};

template< class _obj, class _function, class _arg0, class _arg1 >
class MemberFunctionWrapper
{
    const _function m_memberfunction;

public:
    MemberFunctionWrapper( _function memFn )
        : m_memberfunction( memFn )
    { }

    void call( std::shared_ptr<void>& obj,
               const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<void>>& args )
    {
        m_memberfunction( *static_cast< _obj* >(obj.get()),
                          *static_cast< _arg0* >(args.at( 0 ).get()),
                          *static_cast< _arg1* >(args.at( 1 ).get()) );
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> i( new int( 88 ) );
    std::shared_ptr<string> s( new string( "hello" ) );
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo( new Foo );

    std::shared_ptr<void> iVoid = std::static_pointer_cast< void >(i);
    std::shared_ptr<void> sVoid = std::static_pointer_cast< void >(s);
    std::shared_ptr<void> fooVoid = std::static_pointer_cast< void >(foo);

    MemberFunctionWrapper
    <
        Foo,
        decltype(std::mem_fn( &Foo::foo )),
        int,
        string
    > wrapper( &Foo::foo );

    wrapper.call( fooVoid, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<void>>{iVoid, sVoid} );

    system( "pause" );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following may help: https://ideone.com/l7yAJN

```
template<typename F> class MemberFunctionWrapper;

template<class Obj, class Ret, typename ... Args>
class MemberFunctionWrapper<Ret (Obj::*)(Args...)>
{
    typedef Ret (Obj::*MemberFunction)(Args...);
    const MemberFunction m_memberfunction;

    template <std::size_t ... Is>
    void call(std::shared_ptr<void>& obj,
              const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<void>>& args,
              index_sequence<Is...>)
      {
          (static_cast<Obj*>(obj.get())->*m_memberfunction)
              (*static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<Args>::type*>(args.at(Is).get())...);
      }
public:
    MemberFunctionWrapper(MemberFunction memFn) : m_memberfunction(memFn)
    {}

    void call(std::shared_ptr<void>& obj,
              const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<void>>& args )
    {
        assert(args.size() == sizeof...(Args));
        call(obj, args, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>());
    }

};
```